# Finding File data from POST in C#

Tags: c#, post, request, request.form

This is probably something blatantly obvious that I'm just missing. Help me, SO! I'm trying to access file data submitted via POST from a web form (not the built in C# ones though.) I have no idea how to do this, and MSDN is singularly unhelpful in this matter.

Here's the three things I've tried so far:

```
Request["file"];
Request.Form["file"];
Request;
```

What else is there? It just seems to be a missing POST data. If it helps, here's the output from firebug:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------149243018821763
Content-Length: 703
-----------------------------149243018821763
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="testsearch.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
Just some plain text data.
-----------------------------149243018821763
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="folder"
ftp://wwwdev.jbu.edu/athletics/resource/media/testsearch.txt
-----------------------------149243018821763
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"
100000
-----------------------------149243018821763
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="u"
username
-----------------------------149243018821763
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="p"
password
-----------------------------149243018821763--
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try...

```
Request.Files["file"]
```

Reflector shows that files are excluded from the Request.Form collection.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using a FileUpload control....  You need to put something like this in your Page_Load.

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToLower() == ".jpg")
                {
                    fileOK = true;
                }
                if (fileOK)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(path,  newFileName + ".jpg"));
```